# Is the Jenkins workspace on the master or the worker?

Tags: jenkins

Who does the actual cloning of the project, is it the master or the agent node? If it is the master, then how does the agent node actually execute the job. If it is the agent node, how can we view the workspace in the browser?

When people ask "where is the workspace" the answer is usually a path, but I am more interested in where that path is, on the master or the agent node? Or maybe it is both?

**Edit1**

Aligned terminology to this: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/glossary/ in order to avoid confusion.

In a Jenkins set up all the machines are considered nodes. The master node connects to one or more agent nodes. Executors can run both on the master or agent nodes.

In my scenario, no executors run on the master. They are run only on the agent nodes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is: it depends !

First of all, although it is not a good practice IMO, some installation let the master be an actual worker and run jobs. In this case, the workspace will be on the master.

If you configured the master not to accept jobs, there are still occasion when a workspace can be created on the master. A good example is when your job is a "pipeline script from SCM". In this case, the master will create a workspace for the job, clone the target repo, read the pipeline, and start needed jobs on whatever slave is targeted, creating a workspace to run the actions themselves. If the pipeline targets multiple slaves, there will be a workspace on each of them.

In simple situation (e.g. maven or freestyle job), the workspace will only be on the targeted slave.

Comment: In my scenario, I have freestyle jobs and no executors are running on the master, only on the agent nodes. If the workspace is on the node where the executor is running, then how can it be viewed in the browser? Is it synchronized back to the master?

Comment: @Igorski As long as the agent is still connected to the master, the master can retrieve information about the contents of the directory via the connection to the agent. Take the agent offline and you'll see that the workspace is no longer listed as link (At least that's the case for pipeline jobs).

Answer (score 1):

I needed to dig a bit deeper to understand this.

1. I ran a brand new instance of Jenkins and I attached a single agent node. I used SSH and I set the remote (agent) root directory to: /home/igorski/jenkins
2. As soon as I attached the node the remoting folder and [remoting.jar](https://github.com/jenkinsci/remoting/blob/master/README.md) showed up in that root directory.
3. I ran a basic Gradle Java pipeline job (Jenkinsfile in the project).
4. The workspace showed up on the slave. Not on the master.
5. From the Jenkins GUI I can access the workspace and see it's contents.
6. At the moment I kill the agent machine I can no longer view the workspace in Jenkins.

My guess is that the remoting.jar somehow does a live sync.

I also ran a freestyle project and I can confirm the same. As soon as the agent is killed I can no longer open the Workspace and I get an error stack trace:

```
 hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to JenkoOne
```

This was much more obvious with the Pipeline job though. There you get a link to the agent that you need to click in order to see the contents. As soon as the agent is gone the link is disabled. And you know exactly on which agent the node is. With freestyle jobs, you just get a Workspace link. There is no indication on what agent it is or if the agent is accessible at the moment.

So, both **Zeitounator** and **fabian** were correct.